# bash brace feature fails when used with variables?

Tags: bash

I am trying to use bash to list the files in the current directory with pattern *{num1..num2}.txt

I have tried to use the bash brace feature

```
ls *{10..20}.txt
```

, which works. However when I set the variable num1 and num2 first and then use

```
num1=10
num2=20
ls a{${num1}..${num2}}.txt
```

, which actually fails. I have used `bash -x` to debug and I found that bash automatically adds single quote to the string `a{${num1}..${num2}}.txt`, which is very weird.

Do you have any solution for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Ignore the accepted answer if at all possible. The use of `eval` really isn't necessary (or a good idea when avoidable). You can accumulate the entries with the loop in an array if you need to run a single command with them all as arguments.

Comment: Do you mean the following loop?
`all=; for i in {10..20}; do all="$all $(ls *$i.nc)"; done; echo $all`

Comment: That loop is wrong for different reasons.`all=(); for i in {10..20}; do all+=( *"$i.nc" ); done; echo "${all[@]}"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ n=3; echo {"$n"..5}
{3..5}
```

so you need to evaluate the outcome

```
$ n=3; eval echo {"$n"..5}
3 4 5
```

Comment: mandatory "eval is evil" comment.

Comment: A lot of people say "eval is evil". I don't usually use it so I don't know why. But at least it gives a solution to this problem:D

Comment: Not for this use perhaps, but one can easily abuse it.